# Interact with HTML on mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DnNkk/) is my code; I am trying to make the button turn black when hovered over.

My current jQuery (again I don't know much still learning):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').mouseenter(function() {
        $('div').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function() {
        $('div').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is fine, but you don't have jQuery in the jsfiddle. You have mootools. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/vCtX6/

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the jsfiddle is that you have not included jquery from the left side..

Also inside the event handler you might want to use `this` to target the specific element instead of using `$('div')` which will target all the divs in the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
});
```

---

You can, however, do the same without using any javascript/jquery.. but just with CSS transitions

```
div {
    opacity:0.5;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
    border-color:blue;
    float:left;
    color:#FFFFFF;

    transition:opacity 1s; /*added this to enable transitions on opacity of divs*/
}
div:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/DnNkk/2/

Answer (score 1):

On the left side menu you have an option `Chose Framework`, you have to add `jQuery`, and you forgot to do it.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnNkk/1/)